# COM server as windows service, cannot pass array as function argument

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, service, com

I'm implementing COM server (using ATL) as Windows service. I have the following method defined in service header:

```
STDMETHOD(SetBytes)(long lenSource, const BYTE* pSource, VARIANT_BOOL *pResult);
```

This method is declared in the IDL file:

```
[
object,
uuid(351C5A5F-3EB8-4CC5-AB79-6DCD27C2F7E0),
dual,
pointer_default(unique)
]
interface ISampleInterface: IUnknown {
  HRESULT SetBytes([in] long lenSource, [in,ref,size_is(lenSource)] const BYTE* pSource, [out,retval] VARIANT_BOOL *pResult);
};
```

I'm calling it from my test application like this:

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
IUnknownPtr unknown_ptr;
HRESULT hr = unknown_ptr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MyLib::SampleManager));

if (FAILED(hr)) {
  ...
};

MyLib::ISampleInterfacePtr sample_ptr;
sample_ptr = unknown_ptr; // no check here, assume sample_ptr is not null

VARIANT_BOOL function_result = VARIANT_FALSE;
vector<uint8_t> flash_data(1000, 2);
function_result = sample_ptr->SetBytes(flash_data.size(), &flash_data[0]);
```

I'm registering service by performing:

```
MyService.exe /regserver
MyService.exe -service
```

Then I'm executing test code step by step. When I'm going to tli file where we can see the following

```
HRESULT _hr = raw_SetBytes(lenSource, pSource, &_result);
```

pSource is absolutely ok and points to the area of memory where my data is contained. But when I'm going further (I'm attached to the service with debugger) and I'm in service's function SetBytes, only one byte from this array is contained in memory area and this pointer points to the different address.

I have tried implementing server via dll (it's registered in the system with regsvr32 [dllname]) and the pointer was absolutely ok in it in this case and all the length was passed, not only one byte.

I'm new to COM technology and wondering where I am wrong.

Comment: Your proxy isn't working right, I don't see a problem with the MIDL attributes.  You never mentioned registering it, make sure you don't have an old one active that was built with the wrong attributes.

Comment: Can you please guide me a bit? What do I do in order to check it? Where can I see it? I unregister previous service ([service_name] /unregserver) and it's all I know about registration for now... I want to understand what's going on though the case with SAFEARRAYs works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could maybe wrap your BYTE array it into a SAFEARRAY.

```
       STDMETHODIMP MyClass::getVariantFromCharArray( char *inputCharArray, UINT inputCharArrayLength, VARIANT *outputVariant)
      {
          SAFEARRAYBOUND saBound;
          char  *pData = NULL;

          saBound.cElements = inputCharArrayLength;
           saBound.lLbound      = 0;

          VariantInit( outputVariant);
          (*outputVariant).vt = VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY;
          (*outputVariant).parray = SafeArrayCreate( VT_UI1, 1, &saBound);

          if ( (*outputVariant).parray)
          {
             SafeArrayAccessData( (*outputVariant).parray, (void **)&pData);
        memcpy( pData, inputCharArray, inputCharArrayLength);
        SafeArrayUnaccessData( (*outputVariant).parray);    

        return S_OK;
    }
    else
    {
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need a `VARIANT` to use `SAFEARRAY`, unless you need to support OleAutomation clients, like scripting environments

Comment: Yes, it's a good way to work with arrays, thank you guys! I don't have a task to support scripting environments right now so I will think whether it's better to leave VARIANT or use SAFEARRAY at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `SAFEARRAY` to pass byte arrays around in COM.