# A call to a COM project won't return the array entirely. First element only

Tags: c++, arrays, com

I've got a COM-object and a client (C++, unmanaged). I'm using a function with next description in .idl file (according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) array type is comformant :

```
[id(8)] HRESULT arrray_test_100500(
  [in] int array_size,
  [out, size_is(array_size)] double array_itself[*]
);
```

and with the following declaration and definition in .h and .cpp:

```
STDMETHOD(arrray_test_100500)(int arrray_size, double array_itself[]);


STDMETHODIMP seSimulationEngine::arrray_test_100500(
  int array_size, 
  double array_itself[]
)
{
  if (array_itself) {    
    for (int i=0; i<array_size; i++)
      array_itself[i] = (i+1) * 1.45;

    return S_OK;
  }
  return S_FALSE;
}
```

And the call from a client looks like this:

```
{  
  double d_arr_machine_state[30];
  int tmp_size = 10;

  HRESULT hr = m_cp_simulation_output->arrray_test_100500(
    tmp_size,
    d_arr_machine_state
  );

  double d_first_dif = (d_arr_machine_state)[0];
  double d_sec_dif = (d_arr_machine_state)[1];

  return b_set_pos && SUCCEEDED(hr) &&
    IS_ZERO(d_first_dif - 1.45) && 
    IS_ZERO(d_sec_dif - 2.9);
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting first element only to be correct. The second one is unexpected and third and forth and so on...on a server's side everything's going well - the whole array is assigned with the values.

And at last but not at least - doing everything absolutely the same way in a new solution (not in a big one where such calls must be implemented), with just two project - one as the server and another as the client, the procedure works properly.

I've spent already two days trying figuring this out and don't have any clue. So, I'm really looking forward for any advice. Please, any feedback would be great.

Thanks in advance.

BTW I cannot go through the execution on the server's side in a debug mode - an inset appears with message "ole32.pdb not loaded". already started to think those things to be connected somehow

Comment: You do know [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)?

Comment: Also, please specify what you mean by "unexpected" values. What would you expect? And what do you actually get?

Comment: Why do you sometimes spell "array" with three r's?

Comment: Have you tried using a SAFEARRAY(double) instead? If so, did you get similar problems with that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [COM server as windows service, cannot pass array as function argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282328/com-server-as-windows-service-cannot-pass-array-as-function-argument)

Comment: For one, you're providing an [in,out]; not simply an [out]. For the marshaller to do its job correctly you need to be fully and accurately descriptive. Secondly, out-params are by-reference. Your code is *almost* there. yes, you can do this with a safe array, but if you set it up correctly including the custom marshaling proxy/stub you can do it like you are trying with a little more work. I don't have my Windows rig handy but I'll be at work in an hour or so and if this is still unanswered I'll try and post something.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, know about that, how does it help here?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg expected values are 1.45 and 2.9 for two first elements - as you can see on checking IS_ZERO(d_first_dif - 1.45) && 
    IS_ZERO(d_sec_dif - 2.9);

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for the respond. trying to apply your advices

Comment: @user3640988 You should edit your question to include the relevant information. Also, you didn't say what your actual values are. JoachimPileborg may have been suggesting that you're getting something like 2.89999986 rather than 2.9, and without the definition of `IS_ZERO`, it's impossible to tell whether your comparisons are correct.

Comment: @EricFinn I've checked it in a debug mode and there was just a zero value. IS_ZERO works properly, exact for the reason you mentioned :)

Comment: This will go wrong in a scenario where the call needs to marshaled across apartment boundaries.  In other words, when the array needs to be serialized.  And you are using the standard marshaller, the one that uses the type library.  Which is incapable of storing the [size_is] attribute, it will look as a `double*`.  So you'll just get one element marshaled.  Build the proxy/stub instead.

Comment: @EricFinn is it reasonable to use SAFEARRAY to pass a set of doubles from one unmanaged project to another unmanaged one? How do you think?

Comment: @HansPassant is it reasonable to use SAFEARRAY to pass a set of doubles from one unmanaged project to another unmanaged one? How do you think?

Comment: @user3640988 I say yes, and I've seen some working code that does something similar. If Hans disagrees with me, listen to him instead.